# How to find public ip address in PowerShell from a restricted internet in windows 11

Tags: networking, command-line, powershell, ip

How to find public ip address of a windows 11 pc using powershell or command prompt.
Tried ipconfig and gip(powershell) both of them shows different ip compared to ip from the browser.

IPv4 displayed in the https://whatismyipaddress.com is showing correct in this powershell command (Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip).Content.Trim()

What if the whatismyipaddress.com or ifconfig.me is blocked? or A VPN connected. Goal is to find the public ip without depending these sites.

Comment: A simple explanation is you can’t. Your machine is only aware of the address it was assigned. If your network is behind a CGNAT it is even more complicated, since technically, you wouldn’t even have a public IP address. What problem are you trying to solve by detecting the IP address of the machine?

Comment: You won't be able to find the IP address without either relying on an external site or looking at the external IP address in your router/VPN setting.    

There are any number of ways of engaging with external sites - you could use a dynamic IP address provider, or get a shell script and log in to that box to get the IP, or run a website on another server and write your own webpage which will tell your IP when its hit. (Its a 2 line PHP script).

Comment: @Ramhound Trying to whitelist IP of the secure laptop to access some firewall enabled services in the cloud. Able to whitelist the ip of a normal laptop with open internet but the ip I see in the secure laptop not getting whitelisted in cloud firewall.

Comment: @davidgo This laptop is connected only to a cloud service provider using VPN. Have only the privilege to read the web application from the cloud service. Most of other open internet ways are restricted.

Comment: @Mcore8x - You are aware that whitelists are incredibly easy to bypass, right? If this is a service in your intranet you should be using the intranet IP address.

Answer (score 1):

> What if the whatismyipaddress.com or ifconfig.me is blocked? or A VPN connected. Goal is to find the public ip without depending these sites.

You'll probably need to depend on *some* external site. If site A is blocked, use site B. And if the system doesn't have any form Internet access, then it won't necessarily *have* a "public" IPv4 address at all. (After all, a common definition of a "public IP address" is "one that's used for Internet access".)

Generally, a system only "has" the IPv4 addresses that it's directly assigned to (i.e. the ones that show up in 'ipconfig'). When the system is behind NAT, its Internet access uses a public IP address that belongs to a *different* system – a router or NAT gateway somewhere along the path, which rewrites the packets *in flight* to have some public address instead of the machine's own private address.

(So if the system has only a private address **and** has no Internet access, then there's no opportunity for such rewriting to happen at all – and no public address ever gets used. In effect, there *is* no public address.)

The only way for your system to know the results of such rewriting (or even to know that it's being done at all) is either to ask the router, or to ask an external system "What IP address am I coming from?". The first method might work if there is only one layer of NAT and only one layer of routing (home routers will tell you their public address via UPnP IGD, and you can try using the `upnpc` command if you can get it installed on Windows), but won't work in any large corporate network. (In large corporate networks, there might easily be more than one "public" IP address – even traffic from the same system might have different addresses put on it depending on situation.)

So you're left with the second method, i.e. asking some remote system. (If you're worried that third-party HTTP services would be blocked, run your own.) This doesn't necessarily need to be done via HTTP – STUN is a common protocol for determining this in VoIP, and there are a few "what is my IP" services that work via DNS (though they cannot reliably detect DNS proxying).

```
nslookup -q=A whoami.akamai.net. ns1-1.akamaitech.net.
nslookup -q=A o-o.myaddr.l.google.com. ns2.google.com.
nslookup -q=A myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com.
```